# Ordnance Survey BoundaryLine Data pre 2014

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

The OS only have Version: 10/2014 of BoundaryLine for download from
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

I asked if they had this data for earlier, and they replied that they did not. Which seems weird, but there you go.

Presumably many other people have downloaded and have their own copies of earlier data files - are any available anywhere?

Comment: Normally, I'd recommend Archive.org's [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) ... but they have a max file size they deal with, and they might not deal with all file types.

Comment: You might try downloading a copy to determine the filename, and then search to see if someone else has posted online something with that same name.

Comment: @joe: good idea, but alas:Your search - bdline_essh_gb.zip - did not match any documents.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't even find the original ... so it's possible that google and bing don't index zip files.  I did manage to find some 2010 data for Lichfield, though : http://datahub.io/dataset?q=ordinance+survey&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySociety.Org has been caching Ordinance Survey Boundary Line data since 2010:

*This is the mySociety cache of OS OpenData, first released 1st April 2010, and other related similarly-licensed data, as allowed under the licences (please read!). Thanks to Ordnance Survey, data.gov.uk, ONS, and everyone else involved in releasing this data! :)*

http://parlvid.mysociety.org/os/